# Imports for "@chainlink" and "@openzeppelinn" are broken

Tags: solidity, web3js, hardhat, brownie

Whenever I try to do an import like the two demonstrated below, they are not recognized. I am using VSCode. Yes I have tried installing and uninstalling many times. If anybody knows why that would be EPIC. Thanks.

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol";
```

Comment: Is your project configured properly? Have you read https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity#project-structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSC Solidity extension can't read Brownie's remappings. I'm assuming that you're getting this error:

> Source
> "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol"
> not found: File import callback not supported
>
> Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol" not
> found: File import callback not supported

**Make sure you set dependencies and remappings correctly in `brownie-config.yaml`**:

```yaml
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1'
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
```

Compile your contracts:

```sh
brownie compile
```

If compiled successfully, Brownie should have downloaded packages, you can confirm it by running

```sh
brownie pm list
```

**Set remappings for VSCode Solidity extension (for example in `./vscode/settings.json`)**.

```json
"solidity.remappings": [
  "@chainlink/=<PATH_TO_BROWNIE_STUFF>/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1",
  "@openzeppelin/=<PATH_TO_BROWNIE_STUFF>/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0",
]
```

Make sure that you got the versions (`@x.x.x`) right across all the config files.

If you're on Linux, `<PATH_TO_BROWNIE_STUFF>` would probably be your home directory (`/home/jjreedv`)

Answer (score 0):

As of [Feb 2022](https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity/pull/322), the remappings code settings for VS Code have been updated to be OS specific.

Here's an example:

```json
{
    "solidity.remappingsUnix": [
        "@chainlink-brownie-contracts/=/home/<USERNAME>/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.4.1",
        "@openzeppelin/=/home/<USERNAME>/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.6.0",
    ],
    "solidity.remappingsWindows": [
        "@openzeppelin/=C:/Users/<USERNAME>/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.6.0",
        "@chainlink-brownie-contracts/=C:/Users/<USERNAME>/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.4.1",
    ],
```

Official README of project:
https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity#platform-specific-remappings